# Ruby list values are identical after assigning different values

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, redis

Sorry for the confusing title, not sure how to describe this issue.

Inside a Ruby on Rails controller I'm creating a list named `@commits`, where each item in `@commits` should contain a hash table whose elements are the values of various properties for each commit. These property values are stored in a Redis database.

Below, I iterate through a list of properties whose values should be grabbed from Redis, and then grab those values for each of 8 different commits. Then I place the values from redis into a different hash table for each commit, using the commit property name as the key for the hash.

```
# Initialize @commits as a list of eight empty hash tables
@commits = Array.new(8, {})

# Iterate over the attributes that need hashed for each item in @commits
[:username, :comment, :rev, :repo].each do |attrib|
    # 8 items in @commits
    8.times do |i| 
       # Get a value from redis and store it in @commits[i]'s hash table
       @commits[i][attrib] = $redis.lindex(attrib, i)

       # Print the value stored in the hash
       # Outputs 7, 6, .., 0 for @commits[i][:rev]
       puts @commits[i][attrib].to_s
    end
end

# Print the value of every item that was stored in the hash tables above, 
# but only for the :rev key
# Outputs 0 eight times
8.times do |i|
    puts @commits[i][:rev]
end
```

However, per the comments above, @commits[0..7] all seem to have the same values in their hashes, despite them being seemingly stored correctly a few lines above. Using the hash key `:rev` as an example, the first `puts` outputs 7..0, which is correct, but the second `puts` outputs the number 0 eight times.

Anyone know why?

Comment: Using global variables like `$redis` is probably a sign of bad design. Is that really necessary?

Comment: It's not necessary and it is bad design for sure, but this is a throwaway project that I'm experimenting with. I would not do this in production.

Comment: Can you show how @commits is being initialized/created before these blocks?

Comment: Oops, had meant to. I've edited to include that.

Comment: I had an idea you were doing something like that. I've added an answer which explains the subtle mistake.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It would help if you show how `@commits` is initialized, but it looks like you've created a structure with multiple references to the same object.

Incorrect, same object recycled for all keys:

```
@commits = Hash.new([ ])
```

Correct, new object created for each key:

```
@commits = Hash.new { |h, k| h[k] = [ ] }
```

You could be using an Array with the same mistake:

```
@commits = Array.new(8, [ ])
```

This will lead to the following behaviour:

```
a = Array.new(4, [ ])
a[0]
# => []
a[0] << 'x'
# => ["x"]
a
# => [["x"], ["x"], ["x"], ["x"]]
```

It can be fixed by passing in a block:

```
a = Array.new(4) { [ ] }
a[0]
# => []
a[0] << 'x'
# => ["x"]
a
# => [["x"], [], [], []]
```

It is highly unusual to see an array pre-initialized with values, though. Normally these are just lazy-initialized, or a Hash is used in place of an Array.

Comment: I think you just missed the `@commits = Array.new(8, {})` update, good guess though.

Comment: Yep, you hit the nail on the head. I misunderstood how the Array.new function initialized the array. Tested and confirmed that your suggestion solved my problem. Thanks!